# How to count the number of ordered sequence in a vector in R

Tags: r

I have the following data set as an example.

```
Data<-c("a","d","c","b","d","a","d","b","c","b","a","b","d","c","b","a","c","d","d","c")
```

I need to find out how many times a < b < c < d, all possible combinations.

I have created a loop (using 4 IF functions) but it takes long time when we have large data set. With this loop the answer is 47 times.

Is there any efficient way to do so in R.

Here is my attempt, but it is very slow when say we have more than 4 letters and large data set.

```
Data<-c("a","d","c","b","d","a","d","b","c","b","a","b","d","c","b","a","c","d","d","c")
set.seed(123)
Data0<-sort(sample(1:100,20))

df<-data.frame(Data,Data0)

A<-df[Data=="a",2]
B<-df[Data=="b",2]
C<-df[Data=="c",2]
D<-df[Data=="d",2]


myfun<-function(A,B,C,D){
b0<-0
f0<-0
for (i in 1:length(A)){
for (j in 1:length(B)){
for (k in 1:length(C)){
for (l in 1:length(D)){

f0<-f0+sum(A[i]<B[j])*sum(B[j]<C[k])*sum(C[k]<D[l])

}}}}

return(f0)
}


myfun(A,B,C,D)
```

---

Many Thanks

Comment: Can you show your loop solution as it is not clear to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `split` to divide `Data0` based on groups i.e `Data`, create all possible combinations using `expand.grid` and count number of times `a < b < c < d`.

```
temp <- do.call(expand.grid, split(df$Data0, df$Data))
sum(with(temp, a < b & b < c & c < d))
#[1] 47
```

If there are many columns and we do not want to check it manually, we can use `apply` and for every row check the difference between consecutive elements with `diff` and count number of occurrences when `all` the values are higher than the previous values.

```
sum(apply(temp, 1, function(x) all(diff(x) > 0)))
#[1] 47
```

Comment: Thanks, is there anyway I can write "a < b & b < c & c < d" in a function way, I mean if I have more than 4 letters, I do not need to do that manually. thanks again